# C++ function inside of a macro missing ;

Tags: c++, function, macros, interrupt

I'm having trouble with writing an assignment for uni in an old Borland c++ standard.
So I have this macro which **HAS** to be used like this: `PREPAREENTRY(9,0);` where the first argument will always range from 0 to 255 and second will always be 0 or 1. Without going into much detail unless necessary it's supposed to automatically generate a unique interrupt function for every entry in the interrupt vector table.
My code is as follows:

```
#define PREPAREENTRY(ivtNo, oldInterrupt)         \
extern IVTEntry ivtEntry##ivtNo;                  \
void interrupt interrupt##ivtNo(...){             \
    ivtEntry##ivtNo.signal();                     \
    if(oldInterrupt)                              \
        ivtEntry##ivtNo.oldInterrupt();           \
}                                                 \
IVTEntry ivtEntry##ivtNo(ivtNo, interrupt##ivtNo);
```

(I've tried not putting `;` on the last line of macro definition, but it still gives me the same error)
When I don't use the macro and switch every `ivtNo` with `9` and `oldInterrupt` with `0`, the code works. But when I use the macro the code can't compile and it gives me this error `Error ..\src\keyevent.cpp 17: Statement missing ; in function interrupt interrupt9(...)`. I've tried moving around a bunch of stuff and writing it several times but it's always either that error or `missing )` error.
I will provide you with more details if needed, but if anyone has any clue what could be causing these errors I'd be very grateful!

### SOLVED

Macro argument and function inside of `IVTEntry` class that I'm using inside of the macro had the same name. So the macro called `ivtEntry9.0();` instead of `ivtEntry9.oldInterrupt();`

Comment: A [mcve] would help (aka a short program that we can compile ourselves and get the same error message). Also can you add the error message you get verbatim? Also the code formatting will look better if you put \`\`\` on a separate line before and after the code.

Comment: `void interrupt interrupt##ivtNo` This doesn't seem like a valid function definition?

Comment: @RahulBharadwaj Might be some Borland C++ quirk.

Comment: How does `ivtEntry9.0();` make sense?

Comment: @aschepler Oh right, I've made a dumb mistake and named the macro argument and function inside of IVTEntry class the same. I've renamed the argument and it fixed the problem, thanks a lot.